# Getting sub string after hh:mm:ss format in Oracle PL sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose Below is a string :

"Rajiv Verma 3/20/2018 3:48:39  Tom has told me to comment here"

I need to get below sub string which is there after hh:mm:ss format always:

"Tom has told me to comment here".

How can this achieve by Pl sql Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a pattern to match a time:

```
DECLARE
  p_input   VARCHAR2(4000) := 'Rajiv Verma 3/20/2018 3:48:39 Tom has told me to comment here';
  p_comment VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  p_comment := REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                 p_input,
                 '\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?(.*)$',
                 1,     -- Start from the 1st character
                 1,     -- Find the 1st match
                 NULL,  -- No flags
                 1      -- Return the 1st capture group
               );
END;
/
```

or in SQL:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         your_string,
         '\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?(.*)$',
         1,     -- Start from the 1st character
         1,     -- Find the 1st match
         NULL,  -- No flags
         1      -- Return the 1st capture group
       )
FROM   your_table;
```

Documentation on Oracle's (perl) regular expressions patterns [can be found here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix003.htm).

Comment: Hi MTO....it's not worked for below format :7:4:44 or 6:29:8,  but it worked for 3:48:39 and 9:17:56....any clue...?

Comment: @TapanMohanty Updated

Comment: Hey MT0...I have changed slightly like this:'\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?(.*)$'.....now it's working fine....Thanks for help